# How to Disable client certificate prompt in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I'm working with X509 certificates with my website. And I have created client certificates for testing.

The issue is that even though a single certificate is installed, chrome shows the certificate selection prompt. We have an option under IE to disable the same but I couldn't find any such option under Chrome.

I have searched but haven't found a satisfactory answer.

The closest I could get to solving the issue was with this [link](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls). This is for Chromium however I have read somewhere that Chrome uses a similar approach for this policy.

Sadly the Windows registry  does not contain such a value :-

Software\Policies\Chrome

Any help with this deeply appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop chrome's Select a certificate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653785/how-to-stop-chromes-select-a-certificate-window)