# How to stop Chrome's Select a certificate window?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm working on a Selenium project and the system I need to test is using an SSL certificate. Every time when I try to login we are getting this "Select a certificate" window which we cannot handle with WebDriver.

[image: Chrome select a certificate window]

I have tried clicking OK button using AutoItx as below. But the `Send("{ENTER}")` is not the best option.

```
if (AutoItX.WinWaitActive("data:, - Google Chrome", "", 10) == 0)
{
   AutoItX.WinActivate("data:, - Google Chrome");
   AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

Is there a way to click on OK button using AutoItX? Or is there a way we can load this certificate when defining ChromeDriver by using Capabilities?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (64-Bit), Win 7 Enterprise:

Create registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
```

Here create new String value (REG_SZ) with name 1

As Value data enter:

```
{"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{}}
```

[This is how the registry then looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8TTG.png)

For more information on this key I found:

> The value must be an array of stringified JSON dictionaries. Each dictionary must have the form { "pattern": "$URL_PATTERN", "filter" : $FILTER }, where $URL_PATTERN is a content setting pattern. $FILTER restricts from which client certificates the browser will automatically select. Independent of the filter, only certificates will be selected that match the server's certificate request. If $FILTER has the form { "ISSUER": { "CN": "$ISSUER_CN" } }, additionally only client certificates are selected that are issued by a certificate with the CommonName $ISSUER_CN. If $FILTER is the empty dictionary {}, the selection of client certificates is not additionally restricted.

on [Automatically select client certificates for these sites](http://getadmx.com/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome%3A%3AAutoSelectCertificateForUrls)

### Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (64-Bit), Win 10 Enterprise:

Create registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
```

Here create new String value (REG_SZ) with name 1

As Value data enter:

```
{"pattern":"[*.]mycompany.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"MyCompanyCA"}}}
```

[image]

MyCompanyCA and the subdomain mycompany.com must be replaced with your corresponding url and issuing company.

Comment: This works well for windows 7 machines, however on windows 10 not. Is there a way of making it work on a windows 10 computer? (chrome v59)

Comment: what is the format of $URL_PATTERN ? Is it a regex pattern or does it use * as a wildcard or just a plain string with no special pattern matching functionality?

Comment: The REG_SZ value will look like this:

   `{"pattern":"[*.]mycompany.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"MyCompanyCA"}}}`

This means that when you go to any **mycompany.com** subdomain, it will automatically use the certificate with a CN (Common Name) of **MyCompanyCA**

Comment: How this solution can be applied on linux?

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple certificates and the one you want to select is not the first one then you will need to apply a filter.

https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls has an in-depth description of the filter values, but you're probably not interested in most of them and can use:

```
{"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"[Issued By]"}}}
```

replacing **[Issued By]** with the issuer of your client certificate. I can't for the life of me manage to get the URL pattern working with anything more specific than [*.], which matches any URL.

Comment: Link does not work anymore; it sends the user to a generic page. :(

Comment: Good spot, updated to what looks like the correct one now.