# disable "select a certificate" (ssl) for all browsers windows

Tags: selenium, ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

I'm running selenium automation on a site that requires you to select an SSL certificate or to use credentials to login (username and password). To enter the credentials I first have to press escape to dismiss the "Select a certificate" dialog. Because the dialog isn't an html element selenium could not reach it so I created an AUTOIT script that presses escape to bypass this, however this was a temporary solution and now I'm looking for something more permanent.

What I wish to achieve is a solution in which I open any browser on my windows machine with the selenium script (chrome, IE, FireFox, etc...) and when I access the site I don't get a "Select a certificate" dialog. Instead the dialog is cancelled and I am automatically transferred to the login page.
Thank you for taking the time. :)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653785/how-to-stop-chromes-select-a-certificate-window

Comment: Not exactly, what I need is to ignore the alert and keep running normally (if i dismiss/ignore the alert I can enter the website with username and password credentials)